# Java string split returns empty results

Tags: java, regex, string

Given input is always going to start with 0 and then follow as:
c1 + occurrence where c1 is the character and occurrence is the sequence of the same character repeating.
For example `aabbaaacccc` becomes `0a2b2a3c4`, characters will be always lowercase a-z.

Now my issue is given input as:
`0x1k1c4t11g3d1m1d1j10f1v1n3e2r3i1e2a1h4a2e1y1z2e1s1a1q1j2r1k2t3h1i1f4j1d2m4p3`
However when I use `String.split()` and iterate through the results I am getting empty strings. I tried using both `split("[0-9]")` and `split("[^a-z]")` but result does not change.

The iteration result for my example is:

```
x
k
c
t

g
d
m
d
j

f
v
n
e
r
i
e
a
h
a
e
y
z
e
s
a
q
j
r
k
t
h
i
f
j
d
m
p
```

Is this a bug in JDK or is there something wrong with my regex?

Comment: When you split on numbers, anytime you have two numbers in a row (like `11`), you'll end up seeing an empty string, because there's nothing between those two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you split by a regex that's is of exactly one number or char, you have an empty string when you get a two digit number for example t11 you get t1 and you loose the final 1, if you want to take the whole number you need to put + after what the regex is looking for, for example in this case you should put.
split("[0-9]+") and you would get the whole numbers no matter how many digits you have.

Answer (score 0):

As Vulcan states in his comment, this is caused due to the existence of at least two consecutive numbers which result in empty String.
Maybe you would like to remove any numbers from the String first or obviously, remove the empty Strings in your resulted array.
for instance:

```
s = "0x1k1c4t11g3d1m1d1j10f1v1n3e2r3i1e2a1h4a2e1y1z2e1s1a1q1j2r1k2t3h1i1f4j1d2m4p3";    
s = s.replaceAll("\\d","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is good idea to use String `split()` in this case. it will be better if you use `substring` and `charAt()` in this case, then try to consider a loop that is going to count number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split by a zero-length pattern. A [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is non-capturing, is the way to go:

```
String str = "0d1j10f1";
str.split("(?=[a-z])");
// result: ["0", "d1", "j10", "f1"]
```

Also, as pointed out in other answers, keep in mind numbers can be multiple-digit.